# Automatically Allow Programmatic Access to Outlook

Tags: python, outlook, exchange-server

There is a Public Shared Folder that exists on a corporate exchange server.

I am trying to connect to the outlook folder, and monitor it for incoming mail.

However, When I connect, my local instance of Outlook prompts me for permission.

Is there anyway to circumvent this prompt?

I tried adding relevant MAPI registry values, but it is still prompting.

Any thoughts?

Registry I am setting (python)

```
opened_key = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Security')
winreg.SetValueEx(opened_key, 'PromptSimpleMAPISend', 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, 2)
winreg.SetValueEx(opened_key, 'PromptSimpleMAPINameResolve', 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, 2)
winreg.SetValueEx(opened_key, 'PromptSimpleMAPIOpenMessage', 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, 2)
winreg.SetValueEx(opened_key, 'PromptOomAddressBookAccess', 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, 2)
winreg.SetValueEx(opened_key, 'PromptOomFormulaAccess', 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, 2)
winreg.SetValueEx(opened_key, 'PromptOomSaveAs', 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, 2)

winreg.SetValueEx(opened_key, 'PromptOomAddressInformationAccess', 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, 2)
winreg.SetValueEx(opened_key, 'PromptOomMeetingTaskRequestResponse', 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, 2)
winreg.SetValueEx(opened_key, 'PromptOomSend', 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, 2)

winreg.CloseKey(opened_key)
```

Comment: Which line of your code raises the prompt? See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for the list of your options.

Comment: The prompt is actually raised elsewhere, when I try and actually access an item in the folder

Comment: I understand that. Still, what is it?

Comment: It will prompt as soon as you try to access `item.Body` there is no prompt for checking `item.Subjet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get prompt when reading the `MailItem.Body` property, your workarounds are listed at http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52.

The registry keys above will do nothing. Your options are Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only), MAPI wrapper such as [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author - Redemption can be accessed form Python) or an app like ClickYes.

Comment: Redemption is working, thank you for the guidance. Had to install a 32 bit version of python in order to get it to work with a 32 bit instance of outlook running on a 64 bit PC -_-