# Autorization to c# Send Mail via outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, mailmessage

I want to send emails from my code, I use outlook 2016 from our intranet with Windows authentication.

My code is

```
 public void sendmail ()
   {


            // Create the Outlook application.
            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            // Create a new mail item.
            Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            // Set HTMLBody. 
            //add the body of the email
            oMsg.HTMLBody = "Test email for body!!";
            //Add an attachment.
            String sDisplayName = "MyAttachment";
            int iPosition = (int)oMsg.Body.Length + 1;
            int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
            //now attached the file
            Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add
                                         (@"P:\\DA.PDF", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);

            //Subject line
            oMsg.Subject = "Test Mail";
            // Add a recipient.
            Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
            // Change the recipient in the next line if necessary.
            Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("mo.ja@gmail.com");
            oRecip.Resolve();
            // Send.
            oMsg.Send();
            // Clean up.
            oRecip = null;
            oRecips = null;
            oMsg = null;
            oApp = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
```

But I get this message :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te6DF.png)

the translation of message : a program tries to access the e-mail address information stored in outlook. If this action is unexpected, click refuse, and verify that your antivirus software is up to date

when I click on the accepter button, the email passes well

Any ideas !!! Thanks

Comment: Most of us don't read French. Please take the time to translate the error message

Comment: The translation : a program tries to access the e-mail address information stored in outlook. If this action is unexpected, click refuse, and verify that your antivirus software is up to date.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861540/automatically-allow-programmatic-access-to-outlook

Comment: When you click accept the email does what? Not sure what you're saying there.

Comment: when i click on accept, the email is sent to the recipient successfully

Comment: So what's the problem then? This is an expected protection for the user, to stop malicious programs from messing with their Outlook or harvesting their data. But would it not be better to send the email directly via the Exchange server (e.g. using SMTP) rather than Outlook interop? I can't think of a reason to do it like this really if all you want is to send an email

Comment: I have already used smtp, but I get the message: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The response of the server was: 5.7.57 SMTP.

I already have this message with Gmail, but I have access to my gmail account, I allowed less secure applications and it works.

will my Api web https solve the problem. otherwise how allowed outlook in our intranet to accept less secure apps.

and thank you